# Converting non trivial String input into integer-tuple in python

Tags: python, string, integer, tuples

so my input data is a List of strings like that:

```
coordIndex = 
[' 8, 9, 6, 4, 2, 0, -1,', 
 ' 11, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, -1,', 
 ' 1, 11, 8, 0, -1,', 
 ' 3, 1, 0, 2, -1,', 
 ' 5, 3, 2, 4, -1,', 
 ' 7, 5, 4, 6, -1,', 
 ' 10, 7, 6, 9, -1,', 
 ' 11, 10, 9, 8, -1']
```

And 
it's supposed to be a tuple of int like that:

```
coordIndex=
[[8, 9, 6, 4, 2, 0],
[11, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10],
[1, 11, 8, 0], 
[3, 1, 0, 2], 
[5, 3, 2, 4], 
[7, 5, 4, 6], 
[10, 7, 6, 9], 
[11, 10, 9, 8]]
```

I am able to erase the whitespace, get rid of comma, parse into int by doing that:

```
coordIndex =  [x.replace(' ','') for x in coordIndex]
coordIndex =  [x.replace(',-1,','') for x in coordIndex]
coordIndex =  [x.replace(',-1','') for x in coordIndex]
coordIndex =  [x.replace(',',' ') for x in coordIndex]
coordIndex =  [x.rstrip() for x in coordIndex]
j = 0
for items in coordIndex:
   coordIndex[j] = tuple(map(int, items.split(' ')))
   j+=1
```

However I have issues with the "-1" from the input data being in a new line. The "-1" is always the delimiter for each tuple-line I have to create but I don't see how this can be achieved in python.

If somebody has an idea, help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
[list(map(int,tuple(i.replace(' ','').split('-1')[0].split(',')[:-1]))) for i in s]

[(18, 19, 7, 8),
 (19, 10, 6, 7),
 (10, 11, 5, 6),
 (11, 12, 4, 5),
 (12, 13, 3, 4),
 (13, 14, 2, 3),
 (14, 15, 1, 2),
 (15, 16, 0, 1),
 (16, 17, 9, 0),
 (17, 18, 8, 9),
 (9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 5),
 (19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10)]
```

Comment: Does it work now? Did a minor change. From what I understand your input should be as the one I've added

Comment: For my understanding, what is the reason for the "s[0]" in the first line? It just edits the first line of s, unfortunatly s (or coordIndex on my behalf) is already multiline, like s = ['18,    19,     7,     8,    -1,','    19,    10,     6,     7,    -1,' ..... ]

Comment: Let me edit my listing in order to make the input really 100% like it is. I thought it might be okay if it is abstract, but I guess I was wrong. This is on me then! One moment please.

Comment: I edited the listing. Sorry about the difference, maybe your example is easy to adept?

Comment: yatu, thank you however for your help up to this point. I'll accept your solution when I made it work somehow.

Comment: ['            8,     9,     6,     4,     2,     0,    -1,', '           11,     1,     3,     5,     7,    10,    -1,', '            1,    11,     8,     0,    -1,', '            3,     1,     0,     2,    -1,', '            5,     3,     2,     4,    -1,', '            7,     5,     4,     6,    -1,', '           10,     7,     6,     9,    -1,', '           11,    10,     9,     8,    -1'] direct copy-pasted from console. Thanks! This is another dataset, but the principle stays the same.

Comment: Okay, try `[tuple(re.sub(r'\s+','',i).split('-1')[0].split(',')[:-1]) for i in s]`, where s is the list

Comment: That makes a proper looking list. However the values are still String and they are supposed to be Int.

Comment: `[list(map(int,tuple(i.replace(' ','').split('-1')[0].split(',')[:-1]))) for i in s]`??

Comment: Worked. You, Sir, are one genius man! Thanks and have a great evening

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer accordingly? I‘ll update my question, too, just for the sake of keeping stackoverflow clean.

Comment: Sure, updated my answer. Lets also clean the answer from comments :)

Comment: Yes, I will do that tomorrow from my office. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: One very last question, I suddenly faced input data like that:  ['18, 19, 7, 8, -1,', '19, 10, 6, 7, -1,', '10, 11, 5, 6, -1,', '11, 12, 4, 5, -1,', '12, 13, 3, 4, -1,', '13, 14, 2, 3, -1,', '14, 15, 1, 2, -1,', '15, 16, 0, 1, -1,', '16, 17, 9, 0, -1,', '17, 18, 8, 9, -1,', ' 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2,1,0,', ' -1,', '19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10,', ' -1'] This however creates Empty Elements like that []. Any idea what can be done about that?

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to not read file line by line, because you're basically need alternative way of enline parsing. Think of:

```
with open('datafile.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.replace(' ', '').replace(',\n', '')
lines = data.split(',-1'))
index = [tuple(l.strip(',').split(',')) for l in lines if l]
```